# Accepting Stripe payments with Android using ParseServer/Bitnami

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, parse-server, bitnami

I hope all is well. I'm fairly new to programming, and my school doesn't offer the appropriate level of Android Development to teach me what I need to know. So please do not mark this down because of "guidelines", I'm just trying to get some help. My instructors refuse to help because they aren't legally allowed to teach what is not offered. So please, please, please do not mark this down.

I am attempting to accept a Stripe payment on my mobile application. I am using ParseServer/Bitnami, and I have made it far enough to send and retrieve the tokenId to charge the card. I just haven't figured out how to charge the card. Please help.

```
    Card userCard = new Card(num, expiryMonth, expiryYear, cvc);

        //  Test the data.
        if (userCard.validateCard()) {
            Stripe stripe = new Stripe(CardActivity.this, "pk_live_----REMOVED FOR SECURITY");
            stripe.createToken(
                    userCard,
                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(final Token token) {
                            //  Get the current user.
                            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                            String tokenId = token.getId();
                            //  Update the token.
                            user.put("tokenId", tokenId);

                            /*Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                            params.put("currency", "usd");
                            params.put("interval", "month");
                            params.put("name", "Membership");
                            params.put("amount", 9.99);
                            params.put("id", user.getObjectId());*/


                            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            // Show error message
                            Toast.makeText(CardActivity.this,
                                    error.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried and what problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

So to build a transaction or create a charge (either as a one-off charge or through a recurring subscription) there are actually two phases.

The first phase is called the "Capture and Tokenization Phase". That's where we use information about the credit card (or other payment source) to create a special string to represent the actual details of the card. I like to think of these tokens as more of a codeword (maybe I just watch too many movies)-- the Crow Flies at Midnight. It's a special way for both you and Stripe to know what card you're referring to, without anyone else being able to eavesdrop and figure out any sensitive information. You do this phase with Stripe.js [1], Elements [2], Checkout [3], or your mobile SDK [4][5].  This phase uses your Publishable API Key and happens on a front-end (HTML/Javascript or Mobile).

The second phase is the "Storing or Charging Phase". You can take that special token or codeword that we made earlier and then either (a) charge it for a particular amount of money or (b) attach it to a Customer and store it for later.  Either approach requires that you use the Stripe API on your backend. The alternative would be to use a Plugin or Integration to do all of this legwork for you.  This phase uses your Secret API Key and happens on a backend web service (PHP, Python, Ruby, etc.)

To create a recurring charge or attach the payment source to a Customer, you would use the Create a Customer [6] API Endpoint.  The `source`-argument would be the Token ID, generated in the first phase.  Then you would use the Create a Charge [7] API Endpoint with a `customer`-argument equal to the Customer ID you've created.

Alternatively, to create a one-off charge, you could simply pass the `source`-argument to the Create a Charge [7] API Endpoint without a `customer`-argument.

Meaning-- you're missing the last step here-- you need to pass your retrieved token to a backend server that you control to make the charge.

Hope that helps!

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js/v2
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/elements
[3] https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
[4] https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios
[5] https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android
[6] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer
[7] https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

Comment: Thank you. I have worked out a way to create a one-time transaction, using the above links, and others. I am working to create the recurring payments for the subscriptions.

Comment: Korben, I have been working this problem and I am still at this brick wall. I am using Back4App with a ParseServer and it allows me to use Javascript functions, but I do not know Javascript. I have found sample code and it led me in the right direction but not exactly where I need to go. Stripe has EXCELLENT Java examples, however this is server side code, and I do not know the appropriate platform to publish this code, nor how to call it from my Android App. Please help, man. I'd really appreciate it.